# react navigation touchable previous screen when stack pop

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When screen change, like use `navigation.goBack()`, cant touch button in previous screen umount upper screen, it looks like delay user interaction.

I want interact directly, before unmount upper screen when disappear animation.
Anything help?

under code is some example.

**Navigator**

```js
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forModalPresentationIOS,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="upper" component={Upper} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**Upper**

```js
const Upper = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const goBack = () => {
    console.log('back click');
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('upper render');
    return () => console.log('upper unmount');
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Upper</Text>
      <Button onPress={goBack} title="goBack" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Upper;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Home.tsx**

```js
const Home = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const goUpper = () => {
    console.log('goupper click');
    navigation.navigate('upper');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('home render');
    return () => console.log('home unmount');
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Button title="goUpper" onPress={goUpper} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGbuc.gif)

real my company project, it work android, i dont know why...

Comment: have you tried it on the real device, without console logs and not in dev mode?